# Symfony3 + VichUploaderBundle + custom upload directory

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, symfony-2.8, vichuploaderbundle

I have setup VichUploaderBundle with custom file namer and it works fine..

my relevant config.yml:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: '/uploads/products'
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/products'

            namer: namer.product_image
            #namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            #namer: vich_uploader.namer_origname
            #namer: vich_uploader.namer_property

            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

my custom namer:

```
public function name($obj, PropertyMapping $mapping)
{
    $file = $mapping->getFile($obj);

    $new_name = $this->generateRandomSecret();

    if ($extension = $file->guessExtension())
    {
        $new_name = $new_name .'.'. $extension;
    }

    return $new_name;
}
```

However, i want to use custom path to upload file.

I save needed upload path to session variable "upload_files_path" 
in controller and retrieve said path in the namer.

It saves to database (id, image_name, udated_at), 
but does not write file to filesystem!

When i call

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(product, 'imageFile') }}" />
```

in the template it returns file path prepended with "/".
I can not figure out how to make it work.

Here is my configuration for custom file path:
So i edited "uri_prefix" and "upload_destination" to be blank.
edited config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: ''
            upload_destination: ''

            namer: namer.product_image

            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

my updated custom namer:
Here i concatenate upload path with new file name.

```
public function name($obj, PropertyMapping $mapping)
{
    $file = $mapping->getFile($obj);

    $new_name = $this->generateRandomSecret();

    if ($extension = $file->guessExtension())
    {
        $new_name = $new_name .'.'. $extension;
    }

    $upload_path = $this->container->get('session')->get('upload_files_path');

    $full_path = $upload_path . $new_name;
    return $full_path;
}
```

Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sessions inside your namer, since namer must be stateless.
To customize directory you can use a directory namer. see docs at https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/namers.md#directory-namer